# Why was "for" used in this case?

Tags: gerunds

I came across this sentence and was surprised that the gerund was used instead the infinitive with to:

*The best way **for promoting** a service is to give customers what they want and to satisfy them.*

Why is it not written "to promote" ?Is it a mistake? I don't think so . Is there a difference in the meaning between for and to in this case?
Would it be possible to write
"The best way of promoting a service"

Comment: Yes, **the best way of** is more usual than **the best way for** but both are possible and equivalent to the use of the infinitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *way* (in the sense of "method", "means") normally takes a *to*-infinitive clause, or *of* followed by an *-ing* clause, rather than a complement introduced by *for*.

So

> The best way to promote a service

or

> The best way of promoting a service.

The example you found *the best way for promoting a service* is understandable, but not idiomatic. Maybe it was written by somebody who is not a native English speaker.